# Segmentation fault using threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a seg fault within this code, but I can't find the problem anywhere. It compiles just fine with -lpthread, but it just won't run. This program takes in an integer from the command line and then creates a new thread to calculate the collatz conjecture using that value. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void print_con();
void calc_con(int *n);

int * values[1000];

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
        int* num;
        *num = 15;
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, (void *)&calc_con, (void *)num);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        print_con();
        return 0;
```

}

```
void calc_con(int *n)
{
        int i = 0;
        int * x;
        *x = *n;
        *values[0] = *x;
        while(*x > 1)
        {
                if(*x % 2 == 0)
                        *x /= 2;
                else if(*x % 2 == 1)
                {
                        *x *= 3;
                        *x++;
                }
                i++;
                *values[i] = *x;
        }
        pthread_exit(0);
}

void print_con()
{
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
                if(*values[i] > 0)
                        printf("%d", *values[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: and where does it go wrong. Run it under a debugger

Comment: `int* num;
        *num = 15;` dereferencing an uninitialized pointer... that's _undefined behaviour_

Comment: Compiling with clang using `-Wall` generates three warnings, all of which need to be fixed before your code even has a chance of running correctly. So no, your code does *not* compile fine.

Answer (score 3):

okay you *need* to pass a `void *` as an argument to `pthread_create`, but you still need to respect the basics:

```
int* num;
*num = 15;
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, (void *)&calc_con, (void *)num);
```

Here `*num = 15;` you're writing `15` to an *uninitialized pointer*. That's *undefined behaviour*.

I would do:

```
int num = 15;
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, &calc_con, &num);
```

note that you don't have to cast to `void *` from pointers on non-void. Since `num` is declared in the `main` routine, you can pass a pointer on it to your threads safely.

note that as pointed by dasblinkenlight, you also have to fix the recieving end, in `calc_con`, which has the same issue:

```
int * x;  // uninitialized pointer
*x = *n;  // copy data "in the woods"
```

just dereference into a local variable and you have your value:

```
int x = *((int *)n);
```

and another one:

```
int * values[1000];
```

is an uninitialized array of integer pointers, not an array of integers like you're intending. It should be

```
int values[1000];
```

then

```
values[0] = x;
```

(it's not because there's a lot of `*` operators that it's good code)

Comment: I did everything suggested by you, and I still have a seg-fault. It literally makes no sense.                                                                                      
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, (void*)&calc_con, &n);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);

Comment: the problem lies in the `calc_con` routine then. are you still using uninitialized pointers? running a debugger on your code would help even more than our proof-reading.

Comment: check my last edit, you have another dereferencing issue. Why making things more complex than they should be?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an `int` to your thread using a `void*`. This will work on many platforms, but there is no guarantees that the number would "round-trip" correctly. Once you get pointer back, you save it in a dereferenced uninitialized pointer, which is incorrect.

Pass a pointer to `num` instead, and copy the pointer into `x` directly:

```
void calc_con(void *n);
...
void calc_con(void *n) {
        int i = 0;
        int * x = n;
        *values[0] = *x;
        while(*x > 1) {
                if(*x % 2 == 0) {
                        *x /= 2;
                } else if(*x % 2 == 1) {
                        *x *= 3;
                        *x++;
                }
                i++;
                *values[i] = *x;
        }
        pthread_exit(0);
}
...
int num = 15;
pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, calc_con, (void *)&num);
```

Comment: why casting `num` to `void *` ? nice catch with the value passed as `void *`.

Comment: note that `*values[0] = *x;` is also wrong. OP uses dereferencing with uninitialized pointers everywhere.